# How to bind action creator to component in redux thunk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, thunk

I'm trying to bind my action creator to react component.

Please find below code snippet:

```
import { updateCities } from '../../redux/actions/home';

class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.updateCities = updateCities.bind(this);
    this.something = 'some value';
  }

  render() {
    const { updateCities, home } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <input
            onChange={e => {
              const searchValue = e.target.value;
              updateCities(searchValue);
            }}
          ></input>
```

my action creator:

```
export const updateCities = searchValue => async dispatch => {
  console.log(this.something); // **undefined**
}
```

Why the result is undefined?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

First I'm assuming your connecting your component with connect from `react-redux` since I can't see this in the code you posted.  But if you are logging an undefined value I'm assuming you have this component connected but I have to post this just to make sure.

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { updateCities } from '../../redux/actions/home';

class Home extends React.Component {
  // Your component
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  // your mapped state if you have one else put null where mapStateToProps is in your connect function
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {updateCities})(Home);
```

Now that said your not passing `this.something` to your updateCities function. You have the following:

```
export const updateCities = searchValue => async dispatch => {
  console.log(this.something); 
}
```

How would this function know what `this.something` is when you don't assign a value for it and you don't pass it to the function.

If you want to log the something value then you need to pass it to the function and assign a value for it eg:

```
export const updateCities = something => async dispatch => {
  console.log(something); 
}
```

and in your component you would pass `this.something` into your function like `updateCities(this.something)`

Now if what your are trying to do is log the searchValue then log the searchvalue in your updateCities function

```
export const updateCities = searchValue => async dispatch => {
  console.log(searchValue);
}
```

Comment: The problem with your example that I need to update the "something" and not only use him inside the action creator.
For example: If I'm updating the something to "something else" so the something property inside the constructor should update too.

Comment: How are you planning on updating the something value? Your example code is very confusing what you are trying to do because you are passing the searchValue to your updateCities function but in your updateCities function you are trying to console log the `this.something` value.  What is your plan for this code.  Is it the searchValue you are trying to pass to the updateCities function or `this.something`  and if it is `this.something` how are you planning on updating this value.